# Det and MatrixRank freezes on SparseArray with nonzero default value

Tags: bugs, sparse-arrays, crash

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 9.0.1 or earlier**

---

Why does the following simple code never come to an end (at least with version 8)

```
n = 5;
mat = SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1, {n, n}, -1/(n - 1)];
MatrixRank[mat]
```

when the following clearly doesn't cause any problem?

```
n = 5;
mat = Normal@SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1, {n, n}, -1/(n - 1)];
MatrixRank[mat]
```

The same issue appears to exist with `Det` instead of `MatrixRank`.

Comment: The problem does not seem to exist on newer versions, I'd suggest upgrading.

Comment: On V8.0.4 (Mac) it more or less immediately crashes the kernel.  The problem seems to be mixing `Integer` and `Rational` -- obviously a bug.  Here's a workaround: `mat = SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1/2, {n, n}, -1/(2 (n - 1))]`.  Then `MatrixRank[mat]` and `Det[mat]` return values.  You would have to multiply the determinant by `2^n`, but it returns zero.

Comment: The question code also crashes v7, and the workaround from @Michael works there too.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Are you able to check this in version 9?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's fixed in V9.0.1.  I'll update the notice.  Can't check 9.0.0.